Run scripts in different terminals with env variables
I try to loop through some scripts which are in a directory. Before run the scripts I need to setup a number of env variables.
My last attempt looks like this
konsole --noclose --new-tab --workdir $dev_home/someDir -e "export BASEDIR=/home/pathA && export CONFIG=/home/pathB/etc/dev && script/$srv" &

But this opens a terminal with a warning and an error which I dont really know why
Warning: Could not find 'export', starting '/bin/bash' instead.  Please check your profile settings.

/bin/bash: BASEDIR=/home/pathA: No such file or directory

while in the parent console the scripts prints
❯ "Could not find binary: " "export"
"Could not find binary: " "export"
"Could not find binary: " "export"
"Could not find binary: " "export"
"Could not find binary: " "export"
"Could not find binary: " "export"

Before that I tried to put the export in a function and the call the konsole passing this function. ex konsole --noclose --new-tab --workdir $dev_home/openQA -e $func params &
Can someone explain how can this work?

Beginners keep on thinking they want this; but the proper solution is to run the command in the background with output to a log file, which you can then examine from any terminal, or ignore.

-e expects the name of a single command and zero or more arguments for that command, not arbitrary shell code.

It's simpler not using shell &&.
konsole --noclose --new-tab --workdir "$dev_home/someDir" -e env BASEDIR=/home/pathA CONFIG=/home/pathB/etc/dev "script/$srv" &

